# programming a range of data : Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, range, octave

I have this program, something related with statistic.

```
maximo = max(muestra);
minimo = min(muestra);
rango = maximo - minimo;
num_intervalo = round(1 + 3.322*log(length(muestra)));
amplitud = rango/num_intervalo;

rango_intervalo = [];
for i=1 : num_intervalo + 1
    if i == 1
        rango_intervalo(i: num_intervalo + 1) = minimo;
    else
        rango_intervalo(i: num_intervalo + 1) = rango_tabulado(i) + amplitud;
    end
    if i == num_intervalo + 1
        rango_intervalo(i: num_intervalo + 1) = maximo;
    end
end
rango_intervalo = rango_intervalo';
```

the intention is to create nine (or k intervals) intervals, where each interval has it ranges:

```
[1.580 - 2.587]
[2.587 - 3.594]
.
.
[9.636 - 10.650]
```

With code that I've programmed, it is resulting in 10 data not nine as per the intention.
Any idea, the improve this code?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try the following? (PS: not in front of a matlab installed machine - so just looking at the logic)


`if i == 9`


 `rango_intervalo(i: num_intervalo + 1) = maximo;`


 `end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
intervals = linspace(minimo, maximo, num_intervalo + 1 );
intervals = [ intervals(1:end-1); intervals(2:end) ]';
```

Comment: :excellent code, It works perfect :)
even works perfect with a code I made to absolute frecuency. :)

Comment: @wilbur-naike - if it's so good, why don't you up-vote it? Thanks!

Comment: my reputation is less that 15 :/